# Filtering File Tail on Node Red to execute command

Tags: node-red

I am tailing a log file from an asterisk server (sample log below)... What I am trying to figure out is how to execute a bash script only when a line with the variables RXUNKEY, 2560 is populated to the log.

I am seeing the Split On option and tried filling it in with this:

```
[,]{1,2}\n
```

But that had no effect. How do this get filtered so the log can be used? Do I use the switch function, the trigger function, the template function or the JS function? There is such little documentation I don't know where to begin. Even the Split On option was just a shot in the dark, obviously.

```
20190705043747,TXKEY,1999
20190705043747,RXUNKEY,2560
20190705043747,TXUNKEY,1999
20190705043748,TXUNKEY,MAIN
20190705043759,RXKEY,2560
20190705043759,TXKEY,MAIN
20190705043759,TXKEY,1999
20190705043803,RXUNKEY,2560
20190705043804,TXUNKEY,1999
20190705043804,TXUNKEY,MAIN
20190705043824,RXKEY,2560
20190705043824,TXKEY,MAIN
20190705043824,TXKEY,1999
20190705043825,RXUNKEY,2560
20190705043825,TXUNKEY,1999
20190705043826,TXUNKEY,MAIN
20190705044014,TXKEY,MAIN
20190705044014,TXUNKEY,MAIN
20190705044034,RXKEY,2560
20190705044034,TXKEY,MAIN
20190705044034,TXKEY,1999
20190705044036,RXUNKEY,2560
20190705044036,TXUNKEY,1999
20190705044036,TXUNKEY,MAIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file tail node should give you a single message for each new line added to the log.

You can then use the switch node to check for a string containing `RXUNKEY, 2560`.

This should filter as you want.

The split node is normally used to break up arrays, not to extract values from a string.